# HTML Table break when printing

Tags: html, css

When printing the html table breaks. Secondly i have already tried the below code, there is no difference. And it continues in the next page.

[image: Page1]

CSS:

```
table.report { page-break-after:auto } 
table.report tr { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto } 
table.report td { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto } 
table.report thead { display:table-header-group } 
table.report tfoot { display:table-footer-group } }
```

Comment: table.report { page-break-after:auto }
  table.report tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  table.report td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  table.report thead { display:table-header-group }
  table.report tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
 }

Comment: Please include your code in your question, not in an comment. Also, please provide your HTML code